# How to add eventListener for an array in Lua?

Tags: arrays, loops, lua, coronasdk, addeventlistener

I am trying to add eventListener for each of the balls i created in the screen. I create the balls with for loop and then assigned them to an array. It worked well so far. However, when i tried to add eventListener for each ball in the loop, it gave me phase nil value error. Can you please help me figure it out? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
function ballListener(event)
    if(phase.event=="ended") then
        target.event.isvisible=false
    end
end


for i=1,10,1 do
    a=display.newImage("ball.jpg")
    a.x=math.random(10,200)
    a.y=math.random(10,200)
    a:addEventListener("touch",ballListener)
    table.insert(balls,a)
end
```

Comment: can you post the full text of the error you're receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, some things in your ballListener function are backwards. It should be "event.phase" and "event.target" because "phase" and "target" are properties of the event. Also isvisible should be isVisible. The end result should look like this:

```
function ballListener(event)
   if(event.phase=="ended") then
      event.target.isVisible=false
   end
end
```

I haven't tested the code, so there may be other issues I've missed.

Check out [the Corona API](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/).